# std::shared_ptr vs std::make_shared: unexpected cache misses and branch prediction

Tags: c++, caching, valgrind, branch-prediction

I'm trying to measure the efficiency of pointers created by `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared`.

I have the next testing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


struct TestClass {
    TestClass(int _i) : i(_i) {}
    int i = 1;
};

void sum(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TestClass>>& v) {
    unsigned long long s = 0u;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i) {
        s += v[i]->i * v[i + 1]->i;
    }
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

void test_shared_ptr(size_t n) {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TestClass>> v;
    v.reserve(n);
    for(size_t i = 0u; i < n; ++i) {
        v.push_back(std::shared_ptr<TestClass>(new TestClass(i)));
    }
    sum(v);
}

void test_make_shared(size_t n) {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TestClass>> v;
    v.reserve(n);
    for(size_t i = 0u; i < n; ++i) {
        v.push_back(std::make_shared<TestClass>(i));
    }
    sum(v);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t n = (argc == 3 ) ? atoi(argv[2]) : 100;
    if(atoi(argv[1]) == 1) {
        test_shared_ptr(n);
    } else {
        test_make_shared(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled as `g++ -W -Wall -O2 -g -std=c++14 main.cpp -o cache_misses.bin`

I run the test with `std::shared_ptr` constructor and check the results with valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=cachegrind --branch-sim=yes ./cache_misses.bin 1 100000
==2005== Cachegrind, a cache and branch-prediction profiler
==2005== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote et al.
==2005== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2005== Command: ./cache_misses.bin 1 100000
==2005==
--2005-- warning: L3 cache found, using its data for the LL simulation.
--2005-- warning: specified LL cache: line_size 64  assoc 12  total_size 9,437,184
--2005-- warning: simulated LL cache: line_size 64  assoc 18  total_size 9,437,184
test_shared_ptr
18107093611968
==2005==
==2005== I   refs:      74,188,102
==2005== I1  misses:         1,806
==2005== LLi misses:         1,696
==2005== I1  miss rate:       0.00%
==2005== LLi miss rate:       0.00%
==2005==
==2005== D   refs:      26,099,141  (15,735,722 rd   + 10,363,419 wr)
==2005== D1  misses:       392,064  (   264,583 rd   +    127,481 wr)
==2005== LLd misses:       134,416  (     7,947 rd   +    126,469 wr)
==2005== D1  miss rate:        1.5% (       1.7%     +        1.2%  )
==2005== LLd miss rate:        0.5% (       0.1%     +        1.2%  )
==2005==
==2005== LL refs:          393,870  (   266,389 rd   +    127,481 wr)
==2005== LL misses:        136,112  (     9,643 rd   +    126,469 wr)
==2005== LL miss rate:         0.1% (       0.0%     +        1.2%  )
==2005==
==2005== Branches:      12,732,402  (11,526,905 cond +  1,205,497 ind)
==2005== Mispredicts:       16,055  (    15,481 cond +        574 ind)
==2005== Mispred rate:         0.1% (       0.1%     +        0.0%   )
```

And with `std::make_shared`:

```
valgrind --tool=cachegrind --branch-sim=yes ./cache_misses.bin 2 100000
==2014== Cachegrind, a cache and branch-prediction profiler
==2014== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote et al.
==2014== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2014== Command: ./cache_misses.bin 2 100000
==2014==
--2014-- warning: L3 cache found, using its data for the LL simulation.
--2014-- warning: specified LL cache: line_size 64  assoc 12  total_size 9,437,184
--2014-- warning: simulated LL cache: line_size 64  assoc 18  total_size 9,437,184
test_make_shared
18107093611968
==2014==
==2014== I   refs:      41,283,983
==2014== I1  misses:         1,805
==2014== LLi misses:         1,696
==2014== I1  miss rate:       0.00%
==2014== LLi miss rate:       0.00%
==2014==
==2014== D   refs:      14,997,474  (8,834,690 rd   + 6,162,784 wr)
==2014== D1  misses:       241,781  (  164,368 rd   +    77,413 wr)
==2014== LLd misses:        84,413  (    7,943 rd   +    76,470 wr)
==2014== D1  miss rate:        1.6% (      1.9%     +       1.3%  )
==2014== LLd miss rate:        0.6% (      0.1%     +       1.2%  )
==2014==
==2014== LL refs:          243,586  (  166,173 rd   +    77,413 wr)
==2014== LL misses:         86,109  (    9,639 rd   +    76,470 wr)
==2014== LL miss rate:         0.2% (      0.0%     +       1.2%  )
==2014==
==2014== Branches:       7,031,695  (6,426,222 cond +   605,473 ind)
==2014== Mispredicts:      216,010  (   15,442 cond +   200,568 ind)
==2014== Mispred rate:         3.1% (      0.2%     +      33.1%   )
```

As you may see cache miss and branch misprediction rates are higher when I use `std::make_shared`.
I'd expect `std::make_shared` to be more effective because both stored object and the control block are located in the same memory block. Or at least the performance should be the same.

What do I miss?

Environment details:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Do you get consistent results if you run the test several times?

Comment: It's implementation-dependent. Try testing with other compilers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, yes I do

Comment: Isn't cachegrind just *simulating*, not measuring?  https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#branch-sim says  *Conditional branches are predicted using an array of 16384 2-bit saturating counters.* and that it's supposed to represent a typical desktop/server from 2004.  That simplistic branch prediction is a joke by modern standards, and was overly simplistic for high-performance x86 even in 2004; see https://danluu.com/branch-prediction/.  Intel since Haswell uses IT-TAGE.

Comment: What happens if you use `perf` instead to check the actual performance?

Comment: For real-life performance measurements, you might like to take a look at this: https://developer.amd.com/amd-uprof/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't cachegrind just *simulating*, not measuring?  https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#branch-sim says  *Conditional branches are predicted using an array of 16384 2-bit saturating counters.* and that it's supposed to represent a typical desktop/server from 2004.

**That simplistic branch prediction with 2-bit saturating counters is a joke by modern standards, and was overly simplistic for high-performance CPUs even in 2004**; Pentium II/III had a 2-level adaptive local/global predictor with 4 bits per entry of local history, according to https://danluu.com/branch-prediction/.  See also https://agner.org/optimize/; Agner's microarch PDF has a chapter on branch prediction near the start.

Intel since Haswell uses IT-TAGE, and modern AMD also uses advanced branch prediction techniques.

**I wouldn't be surprised if you have a couple branches that happen to alias each other in valgrind's simulation**, leading to mispredicts for the one that runs less frequently.

---

Have you tried using real HW perf counters?  e.g. on Linux:
`perf stat -d ./cache_misses.bin 2 100000` should give you a more realistic picture for real hardware, including real L1d miss rate and branch prediction miss rate.  perf events like `branches` and `branch-misses` map to some specific HW counter depending on CPU microarchitecture.  `perf list` will show you the counters available.

I often use `taskset -c 3 perf stat -etask-clock:u,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles:u,instructions:u,branches:u,branch-misses:u,uops_issued.any:u,uops_executed.thread:u  -r 2 ./program_under_test` on my Skylake CPU.

(Actually I usually leave out branch-misses because I'm often tuning a SIMD loop that doesn't have unpredictable branches, and there are a limited number of HW counters that can be programmed to count different events.)